# How to create a blank space as button value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have this script below. The '&nbsp;' is not working as space while using it as button's label :

```js
var space = '&nbsp;';
var button = document.createElement("button");
mytext = "A" + space + space + space + space + "A";
button.textContent = mytext;
document.getElementById("buttonarea").appendChild(button);
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = mytext;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="textarea"></div>
    <div id="buttonarea"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using HTML encoded characters, therefore you need to render them as HTML.

```js
var space = '&nbsp;';
var button = document.createElement("button");
mytext = "A" + space + space + space + space + "A";
button.innerHTML = mytext;
document.getElementById("buttonarea").appendChild(button);
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = mytext;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="textarea"></div>
    <div id="buttonarea"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use `repeat` function to repeat space, so mytext variable becomes `var mytext = "A" + space.repeat(4) + "A";`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `&nbsp;` to its Unicode form like this

`var space = '\u00A0';`

This should work.

This is because `innerHTML` DOM method escapes characters such as `&`, `>` into its HTML entities and that is why `&nbsp;` won't work
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Use the unicode equivalent of a non breaking space:

```js
var space = '\u00A0';
var button = document.createElement("button");
mytext = `A${space}${space}${space}${space}A`;
button.textContent = mytext;
document.getElementById("buttonarea").appendChild(button);
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = mytext;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="textarea"></div>
    <div id="buttonarea"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace textContent to innerHTML like the following:

```js
var space = "&nbsp;";
var button = document.createElement("button");
mytext = "A" + space + space + space + space + "A";
button.innerHTML += mytext;
document.getElementById("buttonarea").appendChild(button);
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = mytext;
```

```html
<div id="buttonarea"></div>
<div id="textarea"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add text to button with innerHTML

```
var space = "&nbsp;";
var button = document.createElement("button");
mytext = "A" + space + space + space + space + "A";
button.innerHTML += mytext;
document.getElementById("buttonarea").appendChild(button);
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = mytext;
```